# starting ipa.service failed all related services

Tags: fedora, freeipa

```
[root@ipa ~]# systemctl ipa start
Unknown operation 'ipa'.
[root@ipa ~]# systemctl start ipa
Job for ipa.service failed. See 'systemctl status ipa.service' and                         'journalctl -n' for details.
[root@ipa ~]# systemctl startus ipa
Unknown operation 'startus'.
[root@ipa ~]# systemctl status ipa
ipa.service - Identity, Policy, Audit
      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ipa.service; enabled)
      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu, 2016-02-18 16:11:20 MYT; 33s ago
     Process: 32596 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ipactl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/ipa.service

Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa.domain.com.my ipactl[32596]: Aborting ipactl
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa.domain.com.my ipactl[32596]: Starting Directory Service
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa.domain.com.my ipactl[32596]: Starting krb5kdc Service
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa.domain.com.my ipactl[32596]: Starting kadmin Service
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa.domain.com.my ipactl[32596]: Starting ipa_memcached Service
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa.domain.com.my ipactl[32596]: Starting httpd Service
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa.domain.com.my ipactl[32596]: Starting pki-tomcatd Service
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa.domain.com.my systemd[1]: ipa.service: main process exited,...E
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa.domain.com.my systemd[1]: Failed to start Identity, Policy,....
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa.domain.com.my systemd[1]: Unit ipa.service entered failed state
```

log messages from that time

```
[root@ipa ~]# grep 16:11 /var/log/messages
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa ipactl[32596]: ipa: INFO:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaserver/install/installutils.py", line 617, in run_script
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa ipactl[32596]: return_value = main_function()
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa ipactl[32596]: File "/usr/sbin/ipactl", line 490, in main
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa ipactl[32596]: ipa_start(options)
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa ipactl[32596]: File "/usr/sbin/ipactl", line 261, in ipa_start
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa ipactl[32596]: raise IpactlError("Aborting ipactl")
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa ipactl[32596]: ipa: INFO: The ipactl command failed, exception: IpactlError: Aborting ipactl
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa ipactl[32596]: Aborting ipactl
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa ipactl[32596]: Starting Directory Service
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa ipactl[32596]: Starting krb5kdc Service
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa ipactl[32596]: Starting kadmin Service
Feb 18 16:11:20 ipa ipactl[32596]: Starting pki-tomcatd Service
```

To be able to start freeipa, I have to manually run

```
systemctl start dirsrv@DOMAIN-COM-MY.service
systemctl start krb5kdc.service
systemctl start kadmin.service
systemctl start ipa_memcached.service
systemctl start httpd.service
```

I need to be able to settle this problem before able to upgrade

```
[root@ipa ~]# cat /etc/issue
Fedora release 18 (Spherical Cow)
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)


[root@ipa ~]# rpm -qa | grep freeipa
freeipa-admintools-3.1.0-2.fc18.x86_64
freeipa-server-3.1.0-2.fc18.x86_64
freeipa-client-3.1.0-2.fc18.x86_64
freeipa-server-selinux-3.1.0-2.fc18.x86_64
freeipa-python-3.1.0-2.fc18.x86_64
```

Thanks for sharing your experiences and guidance.

Comment: Fedora 18 is very old and [EOL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/End_of_life). You should update to supported version, which might have this issue already resolved.

Comment: How do I update it? Any detailed guide? Because we are using freeipa to authenticate Zimbra. A seamless upgrade with no downtime would be preferred.

Comment: If you aim for zero-downtime, you should really not use Fedora, but RHEL instead. How to upgrade Fedora is also described on the [Fedora wiki](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading#eol).